# Executar comando no android atraves de notificação por firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

No meu app preciso enviar uma notificação pelo firebase e executar um comando nativo do android.

Por exemplo, estou testando isso ligando a lanterna.

Quando envio a notificação com o app aberto a lanterna liga conforme planejado.

Porem quando o app esta fechado somente recebe a notificação.

Tem alguma forma de executar da mesma forma como se tivesse com o app aberto e ligar a lanterna?

Comment: Tente inserir códigos que você já testou e os problemas que enfrentou, para a pergunta não ficar muito ampla para responder.

Comment: @Wictor Não testei código para rodar com o aplicativo fechado, o teste que eu fiz com o aplicativo aberto deu certo, quero saber se é possível fazer isso com o aplicativo fechado

Comment: Qnd recebe a notificação com app aberto, vc trata ela no seu `FirebaseMessagingService` certo? Qnd ele está fechado, vc pode fazer da mesma forma, mas as informações da notificação virão na sua `Activity` de entrada no Bundle da intent. Algo como `getIntent().getExtras();`.

Comment: @AndréOzawa sim, no metodo onReceiveMessage. Então eu tenho que passar as informações via extras para receber na Activity? O usuario vai ter que clicar na notificação para executar o comando? no caso de ligar a lanterna

Comment: @reemy Exatamente. É a única forma que enxergo neste momento